# Powershell Test-Path in loop, variable path

Tags: powershell

I started learning Powershell yesterday.

I want to write a script that run batches in multiple folders, however only if subfolder contain work_folder.

I have the following folder structure

```
*folder1
    --work_folder
    --script.bat
*folder2
    --script.bat
*folder3
    --script.bat
*test.ps1

powershell
cd C:\a\test\

Get-ChildItem -Path $PWD\*\script.bat | ForEach-Object {

    if ( -not ( Test-Path $PWD\*\work_folder -PathType Container ) )
    {
        Write-host "Not exist"
    return
    } else {
        Write-host "Exist"
    }
    & $_
}
```

If I use

```
    powershell
    $myPath = "$PWD\*\"
```

it will not work as I want.

Please give me a hint or example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple problems with your code. Because you use the `return` keyword if the `work_folder` directory doesn't exist, your script ends entirely on the first folder it spots like this. I think you meant to use the `continue` keyword, which would skip to the next iteration of the loop.

Also, you were iterating on every instance of `script.bat`, when you should have been iterating on every directory containing `script.bat`.

You can write your code a lot cleaner if you do it this way:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path $PWD -Directory).FullName | ForEach-Object {

    if (Test-Path "$_/work_folder" -PathType Container)
    {
        Write-host "Exist"
        & "$_/script.bat"
    } else {
        Write-host "Not exist"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is better. Also I was able to use
Write-Host ("`n" + (Split-Path -Path (Get-Location) -Leaf) + " has been processed")
to output folder name which has just been processed.

Comment: Actually I had to use return. It was causing the loop to iterate again. On the other hand, continue was terminating the script.